# Run python script with specified libraries from a specific folder path

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created a "virtual" environment without using virtualenv library.

I have this structure.

```
./default_env
├── .venv
├── main.py
```

And inside the folder .venv, I have libraries installed.

To install packages in .venv, I simply ran

```
>>> pip install --target=path\to\.venv package_to_install
```

which is ok and works fine.

However my problem is when I try to run python. 
I do not want to run python that uses the global site-packages, I want it to point to my .venv folder. I have read about USER_SITE, but I wasn't able to understand properly how to change it and use it.

When I run python main.py, I get an error (because I have purged all installed libraries). However, I have requests and its dependent packages installed in .venv.

So I am trying to understand how I can run

```
>>> python main.py
```

(with arguments, or changing something ...) but to tell python that the "site-packages" are to be pointed to .venv folder.

This is my main.py script.

```
import requests
def main():
    try:
        import requests
        r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')
        print("get request sent")
    except:
        print("get request not sent")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So when I run it, I get the obvious

```
λ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

because requests is not installed in the global site-packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the python path, either using the PYTHONPATH environment variable or by modifying `sys.path`.

```
# This needs to come before any other imports
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/your/venv")
```

You can also remove other paths to just include your own. `sys.path` is just a `list`.

However why not just use virtualenv? The `venv` package is now part of the standard library.

Comment: Reason is that I have to run it inside a Docker container and for corporate security reasons I can't use venv. However your solution works. Thank you !

Comment: If your application is containerised just `pip install` into the system Python. It's only for your application.